# Tokenization in org.modelmapper

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am trying to find out why the JSON objects that I pass to a Spring controller get accepted with an extra field and when they don't get accepted.

I was looking at the Modelmapper configuration in the documentation and came across this text for `MatchingStrategy.STANDARD`.

```
 - Tokens can be matched in any order
 - All destination property name tokens must be matched
 - All source property names must have at least one token matched
```

The question that I have is: what are these tokens? I'm particularly interested in the meaning because of the third bullet point, since I can't figure out what this means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Token are words of sentence in a String.

check 
[Stringtokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)
 class in java.

[How modelmapper works](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/how-it-works/)

[Token class in modelmapper](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/spi/Tokens.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the Stringtokenizer documentation did help. I already read the two modelmapper pages though :p

Comment: Glad to know it helped :)